# Can we use common (doctrine) orm files in multiple bundles in symfony2 ?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am new to `symfony2`. I am developing a web application in which I have two bundles: first one is AdminBundle and second is UserBundle. I am using Doctrine `ORM` for database. I have multiple tables in which some tables are common to both Bundles.

For now, I have to make `ORM` files in both the Bundles which are common. Is there any way that I can place these common `ORM` files in a single place and use in both the Bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use common Entities and mappings . Just use the right namespace when you are referring to it .  From your Admin bundle , you can access the user bundle 
entities  for example , like

```
$user = new Acme\UserBundle\Entities\User();
$userRepo = $em->getRepository("AcmeUserBundle:User");
```